# Cloud function sometimes doesn't send FCM notification

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a cloud function which reads some data from DB and sends push notification to a user every day at 10:00AM...

This is the function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.qFunction = functions.region('europe-west3').pubsub.schedule('0 10 * * *').timeZone("Europe/Berlin").onRun((context) => {
    admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc('hb')
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
          var token = querySnapshot.data().tokens
          console.log(`Found user to: ${token}`)

          var now = new Date();
          var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
          var diff = (now - start) + ((start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000);
          var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
          var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
          console.log('Day of year: ' + day);
          day += 1;
          
          admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('quotes')
          .doc(day.toString())
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) => {
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                  title: "HB",
                  body: querySnapshot.data().quote,
                  badge: '1',
                  sound: 'default'
                }
              }

              admin
              .messaging()
              .sendToDevice(token, payload)
              .then(response => {
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error)
              })
          })

      })
    return null;
  });
```

However, sometime it sends the notification and sometime doesn't.

For example, two days ago it sent notification successfully:

[image]

And today it hasn't done anything:

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Since I have only one user. Can it be due to cloud functions cold start? If yes, how to prevent this?

Comment: Hi Frank. Sorry, I forgot. But your answer worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling the asynchronous calls in your code correctly, which may lead to your code being interrupted when the container is shut down.

To ensure that your code runs to completion, return a promise that resolves once all asynchronous operations complete. In your case, that should be something like this:

```
exports.qFunction = functions.region('europe-west3').pubsub.schedule('0 10 * * *').timeZone("Europe/Berlin").onRun((context) => {
    return admin //  
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc('hb')
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
          var token = querySnapshot.data().tokens
          console.log(`Found user to: ${token}`)

          var now = new Date();
          var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
          var diff = (now - start) + ((start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000);
          var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
          var day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
          console.log('Day of year: ' + day);
          day += 1;
          
          return admin //  
          .firestore()
          .collection('quotes')
          .doc(day.toString())
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) => {
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                  title: "HB",
                  body: querySnapshot.data().quote,
                  badge: '1',
                  sound: 'default'
                }
              }

              return admin //  
              .messaging()
              .sendToDevice(token, payload)
              .then(response => {
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error)
              })
          })

      })
    // return null;  //  
  });
```

This so-called bubbling up of the promises is quite normal when dealing with asynchronous code. I highly recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [terminating Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and Doug's video series linked from there.